# How to reference strings.js in SPfX? (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'STS' of undefined)

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling

I am trying to migrate my code from Classic experience to SPfX.

My code is using the `SP.UI.ModalDialog`, and I have referenced successfully the `MicrosoftAjax.js, SP.Runtime.js` and the `SP.js` files in my project, and they are visible as source files in the browser developer tools. However the same approach just doesn't
work for `strings.js`, even though I've paid attention that `strings.js` is located under the  `layouts/15/1033` folder instead of `layouts/15`.

I keep getting the error message

> Unable to get property 'STS' of undefined or null reference

and I am unable to find `strings.js` within the source files of my browser developer tools.

The solutions proposed under the links below simply do not apply to SPfX:

https://joshmccarty.com/cannot-read-property-sts-of-undefined-when-using-sp-ui-modaldialog-in-sharepoint-2013/

[Unable to get property 'STS' undefined or null reference - Sp.ui.dialog.js](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/94089/unable-to-get-property-sts-undefined-or-null-reference-sp-ui-dialog-js/144609#144609)

Comment: I would not bother trying to fix SP.UI.ModalDialog. All it does - just display an <iframe> wrapped in a div element centered on a screen. There are so many ready available dialog boxes using for jQuery, React, etc. There is no need to waste time on this legacy dialog that has many unnecessary dependencies on SharePoint and does almost nothing useful for you.

Comment: hello Denis,

thank you for the comment, this is a very valid point.
However within the Office-UI-Fabric, which is the recommended framework for building modern SharePoint user interfaces I find nothing suitable so far. 

In case you have anything specific in mind, feel free to let me know.

Comment: How about this dialog? http://plnkr.co/edit/tPZ8GJ?p=preview  You have full control of the HTML and styles. If you don't like styling or something else - just modify it a little.

Comment: You can just add an <iframe> tag with no border in the body of this dialog. Then the only minor challenge is to detect the events that should cause this dialog to close.

Comment: Hello Denis,

Thank you for your suggestion.
In my case the opportunity to display progress, provided by showWaitScreenWithNoClose is cruicial, hence decided to take advantage of the built-in loading indicator (https://thechriskent.com/2017/05/22/taking-advantage-of-the-loading-indicator-in-the-sharepoint-framework/)

agree with you, trying to update legacy components is a waste of time.